# I can't save the preferred domain in Webmaster Tools

Tags: google-search-console

I just want to save my preferred domain as `www.example.com` in Webmaster Tools but it simply shows the following error message:

> Part of the process of setting a preferred domain is to verify that
>   you own `http://example.com/`. Please verify `http://example.com/`.

I can't save the setting, any idea why this is happening?

Note: I already verified the www version, I have no idea to verify the no-www version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set the preferred domain, you need to verify both the `www` version and the `no-www` version in Webmaster Tools.

Comment: I verified the www version, now how do I verify the no-www version, I have no idea to do this

Comment: Just add the domain without the www in Google WMT as well as the www version.

Comment: I have a problem, I verified both www and non-www version, I set my .htaccess redirection on my site ( I use www.example.com) , yet when I want to set preferred domain(www) in my VERIFIED non-www version in search console, it says - Part of the process of setting a preferred domain is to verify that you own ..... . BUT not only is my www version is verified in console, it is also indexed well.Now, I see that the non-www version has no data whatsoever in console. The only problem is that I cant set the www preferred domain in site settings of non-www .

Answer (score 2):

I run into the same problem, added both www and non-www, removed them, added again, verified both with multiple methods, but nothing. Finally I found out that I added `https` versions only and that is not enough for Google, and after I added both www and non-www with `http` (so actually FOUR versions of the same domain), finally Google let me set the preferred option.